# Is there a way to do a vertical line in HTML without using CSS?

Tags: html, alignment, vertical-alignment

On the left, I have buttons and the rest of the screen is a table, and I need a vertical line to act as a separator between the two but without any use of CSS/styles/classes.

Here is the base code:

```html
<section align="left">
  <div id="buttons">
    <button type="button">Fire</button>
    <br>
    <button type="button">Water</button>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- NEED A VERTICAL LINE HERE -->

<section align="center">
  <table id="pokemons">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h5>Charizard</h5>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h5>Blastoise</h5>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <br>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h5>Pikachu</h5>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h5>Squirttle</h5>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
```

I currently have this (for some reason in online editors the table isn't aligned to the middle, but on my local code it's fine):
[image]

I need this:

[image]

Comment: FYI, a line break element isn't a valid child of a table. You shouldn't be using them for spacing anyway.

Comment: I'm curious. What possible scenario would impose these restrictions?

Comment: You already have invalid HTML anyway. The section element doesn't have an align attribute, which is not a global attribute. It works in some cases because browser vendors have pity on you. :)

Comment: It's not valid as in it causes issue or it's not standard practice? How else would you do X by Y tables in HTML?

Comment: See permitted content: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Comment: So basically you're breaking several valid rules in order to not break other (presumably less valid) rules.

Comment: To answer your question, HTML isn't intended to be used without CSS (or at least inline styles) anymore. No one does it. I challenge you to find a site on the web built in the last decade (or two!) without one or both.

Comment: The `align` attribute has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) for about 20 years, too.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to avoid using CSS, then your page will look atrocious.
2. There is not really a way to do that. I would make an `<hr>` tag and use `transform: rotate(90);` in your CSS.

I'm sorry but you will have to use CSS. No way around it, unless you use CSS or JavaScript.

Comment: There are ways around it but too convoluted to express and shouldn't be used. Avoiding CSS does not automatically make one's page "atrocious".